Is it possible to return a user ID from the database in a response when signing in or verifying a user in AWS Cognito?
I'm currently working on an AWS Cognito setup where I need to store user information in a MySQL database during the pre-signup trigger. I want to use an auto-incremented primary key (PK) in the database rather than using the Cognito username as the PK.
So far, I have successfully validated and inserted user data into the MySQL database.
However, I've faced difficulty in returning the auto-generated primary key from the database within the Cognito trigger response. Modifying the event object in the triggers to include this data has not been successful.(Example below)
  event.response.userAttributes = {
            ...event.response.userAttributes,
            'custom:userId': savedUser.id.toString()
        };

        return event;

I need a way to return the userId from the database (in PreSignUp or PostConfirmation triggers) to the user so the user can call upon other endpoints
